# Testing array issue

Tags: java

I am stuck on an issue that I cannot seem to resolve. I cannot seem to to test my code correctly. My code is as follows

```java
public static int sum13( int[] nums) {
            
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i <= nums.length - 1; i++){
        if( nums[i] != 13){
            sum += nums[i];
            if(i > 0 && nums[i-1] == 13)
                sum -= nums[i];
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
        
        
public static void main(String[] args) {
}
```

If I try to put `System.out.println(sum13([1,2,2,1])` I am met with several errors relating to the `[]` as well as the `,`. I cannot figure out, what it is that I've done wrong.

Return the sum of the numbers in the array, returning 0 for an empty array. Except the number 13 is very unlucky, so it does not count and numbers that come immediately after a 13, also do not count. `sum13([1, 2, 2, 1])` →6
`sum13([1, 1])` →2

Comment: `sum13(new int[1,2,2,1]);`

Comment: as @rigon said below, the previous value can never be 13 in your code

Comment: It is not completely clear for me from your question.
If input array is [1, 20,10,-1,-5,40,13,6,7,4]
Which numbers will not go to sum: 13,6 or 13,6,7,4 ?

Comment: The task is: "so it does not count and numbers that come __immediately__ after a 13 also do not count". So 13 and 6 will not go to sum.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to add flag to know when the previous value was 13. In that way, you don't have to deal with edge cases.

```java
public static int sum13(int[] nums) {
    int sum = 0;
    boolean was13 = false;
    for(int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        if(nums[i] == 13) {
            was13 = true;
        } else {
            if(!was13)
                sum += nums[i];
            was13 = false;
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution with some test cases:

```
public static int sum13(int[] numbers)
{
    int sum = 0;
    int prev = 0;

    for (var number : numbers)
    {
        if (number != 13 && prev != 13)
        {
            sum += number;
        }

        prev = number;
    }

    return sum;
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    System.out.println(sum13(new int[]{}));
    System.out.println(sum13(new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}));
    System.out.println(sum13(new int[]{13, 1, 13, 13, 2, 3, 4, 5}));
}
```